# Express + Typescript + Objection pass model to super class using generic type not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js, objection.js

```
class BaseService<Models> {
  
  public m: Models;

  constructor(model: Models) {
    this.m = model;
  }
}


class MyService extends BaseService<UserModel>{
  
  constructor() {
    super(UserModel);  //It is require new keyword
  }

}
```

We are using **knex.js** with **Objection.js** models.
I'm able to run queries in **MyService** class.
e.g.

```
const user = await UserModel.query().findById(1);
```

But instead i want a base service that to set Model using generic type.

What i need from child class id.

```
super(UserModel);  //It is not working
```

If i pass UserModel using new keyword then error removed but queries not working

```
super(new UserModel())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDKCBOA3AlsBAeAsgPYAmCIEAfNAN4BQ0090ADgK4BGI20AtgFzQipcgG5aTYIQB2EAC6pWwWYVQAKHiTIChZCAEoaTBrIAWmCADoe0ALy9NIMQwC+tV7VCQYAVQhodIDTunlCCAJ4oGNgI0AgAHrIIUsQw8H6RWDi4smHMCIQAZtC+-g4UdAwS0nIKSiqqBhUM0BCseWolqAF6IgwA9H0AkrLQ5tCoCACOrJgT0FIIAO7QANYIYYsqxEzu7gvL+BFomQgNIkA)

You tried to pass class to super class, but it expected **instance** of that class

```js
class BaseService<Models> {
  
  public m: Models;

  constructor(model: Models) {
    this.m = model;
  }
}

class UserModel {}

class MyService extends BaseService<typeof UserModel>{
  
  constructor() {
    super(UserModel);  //It is require new keyword
  }

}

new MyService();
```